# How to map full json object in swift?

Tags: swift, mapping

How to map full response object into a key in swift?

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var id = String()
    var fullResponse = NSDictionary()

    required init?(map: Map){

    }


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
    // don't know how to map the full json from the repose to the fullResponse key.
        fullResponse <- map // map returns empty
    }
}
```

I don't know how to map the entire json object to a key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a FullResponse Class. and map like

```
class Response: Mappable {
var id : String?
var name : String?

required init?(map: Map){

}


func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
fullResponse key.
    name <- map["name"] 
}
```

}

once you will get the response

```
let jsonData = response.data
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
let yourResponse: Response? = Mapper<Response>().map(JSON: json!!)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: fullResponse <- map["yourfullResponseKey"]

Comment: I don't have the full response key. Its from response. so am just mapping the response for the needed key and one separate key to map for the reposonse JSON.

Comment: reposes will be like

Comment: {"id":"123","name":"some name","date":"some date"}

Comment: some more data like that in the response. I just need only few of them 4 or 5. Response will be 10 to 15 keys.

Comment: please check the answer i have updated..hope this ll help

Comment: Thank you for the response. It mapped the response perfectly but still it won't have a key within it with full response.

Comment: I posted my answer above. i hope that it will fit to use. if its wrong. please provide your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here i did to make a key within the map class, it has full response in it.

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var id = String()
    var name = String()
    var fullResponse = NSDictionary()

    required init?(map: Map){

    }


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        fullResponse <- map 
    }
}
```

On the response from the request

```
let jsonData = response.data
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? NSDictionary{
   response.result.value?.fullResponse = json!
}
```

I don't know it's a correct procedure to do it. But it does the trick.